# WebService ERROR API not working properly?

Tags: php, prestashop, categories, prestashop-1.7, android-webservice

I have trouble whit the web service API i have prestashop 1.7.6.4. When i generate an API key for my store android app i just get some products (like 20 products) and i don't get the other products and also i didn't get Categories from website.

I followed correctly the API documentations :

- I  Enabled the webservice ( generate a API key with Enable Status  - key description - i activate all Permissions ).

When i tested the APIkey i found in categories errors:

**ERROR IMAGE**

[image: SCREENSHOT]

THIS IS THE ERROR :
**"Trying to get property 'php_self' of non-object (/home/kfd/public_html/override/classes/Category.php, line 14)"**

**And this is error folder in /override/classes/Category.php :**

**FOLDER IMAGE**

[image: SCREENSHOT]

Could you please help me to solve this issue, Or tell me what the problem is it in order to try fix it ,I would be very grateful for your help !

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

I found a newbie solutions , I Rename Category.php to Categories.php folder! Then everything worked perfectly